# 3+ electron wave function expansion coefficients for atoms

Tags: wavefunction, atomic-physics, specific-reference, ground-state

I was curious if anyone knows of any published coefficients for 3+ electron ground state wave function expansions. For example, I have recently come across a paper "Ground State of the Helium Atom" by Toichiro Kinoshita which gives coefficients for a two-electron system. I have done quite a bit of searching for coefficients for 3 electron systems, but most papers only report the ground state energies that they achieve, but not the associated coefficients of the wave function expansion.

The reason I would like to find such coefficients is that I am interested in visualizing the ground state probability density distributions for multi-electron atoms (this will be obviously limited to small atoms of course) so that I can get an intuitive feel for more complicated systems.